# Iteration problem for $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem here with Iteration question:
$$
f(t)=2 \sec⁡t+2t-3,\;\text{where }t=0.4\text{ and }t=0.5.
$$
Now I need to show that the equation $f(t)=0$  can be rearranged to give the iterative formula
$$
t_{n+1}= a+\frac{b}{\cos t_n}
$$ 
I cant figure out how to get values for $a$ and $b$, however they are supposed to be $a= 3/2$, $b= -1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sec(t) = \frac{1}{\cos(t)}$ so $0 = f(t) = \frac{2}{\cos(t)}+2t-3$.

Move $2t$ to the other side of the equation and divide by $-2$ to get your answer.

Comment: Thank you :) this makes perfect sense. Im self studying math right now so having problems with a lot of simple stuff.